# List item value is always 0 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

Working a page of buttons which populates a textarea with the value of the buttons.

This works fine for items that are buttons, but cannot get it working for list items.

I have to use a list item since some buttons have a drop down.

jsfiddle shows the list item alerting 0 even thought it does have a value.

http://jsfiddle.net/hsw32zv8/

```
<li class='item_value' value='value'>
  <a href='#'>Click</a>
</li>

<br><br>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-success item_value' value='value2'>Click 2</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".item_value").on('click',function(){
  alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

`value` is not a valid attribute for the `li` element (unless it's in an `ol`, but that seems unlikely given your issues and the fact the value of the attribute you had was a string not a number), nor does the DOMElement for that tag type have a `value` property.

Adding non-standard attributes to your markup will render the page invalid and may lead to JS and UI problems. If you want to create a custom attribute, use `data-*`:

```
<li class="item_value" data-value="value">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
</li>
```

```js
$('.item_value').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).data('value')); // = 'value'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[`li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) element doesn't have `value` attribute. However if you still want to get it use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$( this ).attr( 'value' );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsw32zv8/1/)

Comment: Apologies, I did not use your jsFiddle correctly, downvote removed (and comment) - and upvoted ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A list item `<li>` haves a `value` but it only takes numbers (note they should be in an `<ol>`). You gave a string (at interpreted that as 0) so for example:

```
<li class='item_value' value='1010'>
    <a href='#' value="test">Click</a>
</li>
```

Will show up as a value of `1010`. You can get around this by adding a `data-` attribute instead: `data-value="someStringHere"`

Answer (score 2):

just modified your `this.value` to `$(this).attr('value')`.

so the complete code:

```
$(".item_value").on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

hopefully helping